# In codeigniter-base-model how do I use $before_get?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, model

In my CodeIgniter project I am using codeigniter-base-model and extending all my models from there.

In my user model I want to ensure that super users don't get included, unless specified otherwise.

Something like:

```
$this->db->where('uacc_issuper', 0));
```

And I suspect I can use the observer $before_get for this. But I'm not sure how go about it.

Any suggestions pointing me in the right direction will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in $before_get you have give array of method name called before any get query, you need to add those methods in your child model

```
class page_model extends MY_Model{

  protected $before_get = array('method_name');  

  function __construct(){
     parent::__construct();
  }

  function method_name(){
      $this->db->where('uacc_issuper', 0));
  }

}
```

now if you try to get anything with page model this method will be called every time

```
$page = $this->page->get(1);
```